# Multi-level jQuery tabs: secondary level links not opening associated tab section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to put together a multi-level jQuery tabbed navigation system on a page.

i.e. Link 1 | Link 2

If you hover over 'Link 2', the following would display:

Link 1 | Link 2
Link 2's Link 1 | Link 2's Link 2

Clicking on either 'Link 2's Link 1' or 'Link 2's Link 2' will take you to that tabbed section of the page; please note this doesn't result in a new page request, as the content of either of those links were previously hidden as the currently selected tab is 'Link 1', and so just become visible at this point.

The code is the following (note: streamlined for brevity):

```
<span id="form" class="tabs">
<div>        
 <ul>            
 <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>            
 <li><a href="#links">Links</a>
   <ul id="links-tabs-list">                             
   <li><a href="#links_add">Add</a></li>
   <li><a href="#links_manage">Manage</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#images">Images</a></li>
  <li><a href="#more">More..</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="blog"> // content goes here..  </div>
<div id="links">
    <div id="links_add"> // content goes here </div>
    <div id="links_manage"> // content goes here </div>           
 </div>
 <div id="images">  // content goes here.. </div>
 <div id="more"> // content goes here.. </div>
</span>
```

The jQuery tabs are set using, $('.tabs').tabs(), and working fine. Additionally, the CSS is also working correctly with 'Add' and 'Manage' links for the 'Links' section displaying only when 'Links' is hovered. However, when it is hovered, clicking on either 'Add' or 'Manage' doesn't show the 'links_add' or 'links_manage' id divs. Clicking on any other top-level tab link (such as 'Images' or 'More'), however, results in the correct tabbed section being displayed. Hoping someone can let me know what I need to do in order to get clicking on any of the secondary tab level links to result in the associated tab content section to open.

Hope I've been clear! Any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Sorry guys for assuming the CSS isn't needed to investigate a solution. Here it is for the tabs, keeping in mind I'm aware (and not currently bothered) with the on-hover location of the second tab level):

```
.tabs ul { list-style-type: none; padding-left: 0; width: 100%; }
.tabs ul li { display: inline; }
.tabs ul li.final { margin-right: 0px; }
.tabs .ui-tabs-selected a, .tabs .ui-tabs-selected a:hover { cursor: text; text-decoration: none; }
.tabs ul li, .tabs ul li a { color: #DEDEDE; margin-right: 8px; }
.tabs ul li a { text-decoration: none; }
.tabs ul li a:hover { color: #e07979; }
.tabs .ui-tabs-selected a, .tabs .ui-tabs-selected a:hover{ color: #C24B4B; }
.tabs ul li ul { display: none; }
.tabs ul li:hover ul, .tabs ul li.hover ul { position: absolute; display: inline; left: 0; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.tabs ul li:hover li, .tabs ul li.hover li { float: left; }
.tabs ul  li:hover li a, .tabs ul  li.hover li a { color: #000; }
.tabs ul  li li a:hover { color: #357; }
.ui-tabs-hide { display: none; }
```

As for the JS, I'm not using a custom jQuery tabs implementation, and so the only (relevant) JS I'm using is:

```
$(function (){

   $('.tabs').tabs();$('.tabs').tabs();

});
```

If there's anything else needed, please let me know and apologies in advance if there is!

Comment: Are you using jquery-ui tabs or a custom ome? Hard to debug when you only give the mark up.

Comment: Can you please add also the css and the js of the page?

Comment: jquery-ui tabs. Updated original post with the relevant CSS and JS.

Comment: Fingers crossed skafandri will get back with what I'm after, but in the meanwhile any of you guys have any idea on how to fulfill my requirements which have hopefully been made more clear in the below answer?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong! multilevel tabs are not directly supported by jquery, here is the trick:

```
<span id="form" class="tabs">
<div>        
 <ul>            
 <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>            
 <li><a href="#links">Links</a>   
  </li>
  <li><a href="#images">Images</a></li>
  <li><a href="#more">More..</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="blog"> // content goes here..  </div>
<div id="links" class="tabs">
    <ul id="links-tabs-list">                             
   <li><a href="#links_add">Add</a></li>
   <li><a href="#links_manage">Manage</a></li>
   </ul>
    <div id="links_add"> // content goes here </div>
    <div id="links_manage"> // content goes here </div>           
 </div>
 <div id="images">  // content goes here.. </div>
 <div id="more"> // content goes here.. </div>
</span>
```

Comment: Yes, I had it implemented as such before. However, this doesn't do what I'm aiming to achieve, which is to show the second level tab links when you hover over a first level tab that has sub-tabs of its own i.e. in your implementation, in order to open the 'Manage' section, I have to first click on 'Links' and then 'Manage' (2 clicks), as opposed to hovering over 'Links' and then clicking on 'Manage' (1 click).

Comment: Closer, but not quite there as it not only shows the top-level tab's sub-tab links, but also its first sub-tab's (#links_add's) content.

Comment: Hah, unfortunately not :( I can, however, see why I may have come across as seeking this type of solution. What I want is 1) to always be a single click away from any second level non-default tab, which in my example's case happens to be #links_manage, but in the full code there are other examples and 2) for only the second level tab links to appear when hovering a first level tab i.e. content area shouldn't change like it does in your last example. In any case, much appreciate your efforts so far!

Comment: Okay, that is almost there! I believe I had left room for a misunderstanding. I also need the default (first) tab's content to be showing by default on entering the page i.e. the 'Blog' tab's content should be showing in your example code. Sorry for being greedy!

Comment: Heh, afraid not :( It hides the content of the default tab (Blog) once I hover over 'Links', and in order to get its content to re-appear I need to click on 'Blog'. What I want is 1) Blog's content to appear by default, 2) Link's sub-tabs to display on hover, but Blog's content to remain visible and 3) Link's sub-tabs to disappear off-hover.

Comment: Tried being creative with the code you had supplied, but unfortunately went in unproductive circles. Seeing as you've got so close to providing the solution I am after, would extremely appreciate one last effort!